# Insufficient Privilege error while creating a record

Tags: custom-object, master-detail, junction-object, insufficient-privileges

I have a Permission set to assign CRUD permission to a certain custom Object say `CI__c`. This is a Junction object of two other custom object `C__c` and `I__c`. While creating a new record in that junction object with one `C1` and `I1` record, on which the user has access, is getting

```
  CI__c(Jn) ->  C__c(Master-Detail), I__c(Master-Detail)
```

> insufficient privilege error.

Please suggest.

Comment: Sure that you have the following permissions?
1: Create CRUD permission on Cl__c
2.Read CRUD Permission on C__c and l__c
3. Record visibility to the records of C__c and l__c that you are using as parents for the junction object record. Try navigating to the detail pages of those individual records.

Comment: Also is any trigger running for Cl__c from a class on an explicit with sharing context?

Comment: yes all this are in place

Comment: On the master detail field setup page, there exists an option to Select the minimum access level required on the Master record to create, edit, or delete related Detail records. Please check the value in their for the MD fields on the junction object

Comment: If it says Read/Write in there and you only have read access on the parent -> then it would be an issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have demanded for permissions more than what is required for CRUD on junction object `CI__c`.

**Relation:**

```
CI__c(Jn) ->  C__c(Master-Detail), I__c(Master-Detail)
```

**Check the field definitions of the Master Detail:**

[image]

- If you have asked for `Read/Write` then you should have CRUD permission on `C__c` and `I__c` as well
- Change it two `Read Only` and try again, it should work